# How can a ngFor on a filtered array be reevaluated?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm doing a twitter moderator in Angular. For that I have a list of tweets, each tweet being like this:

```
export class Tweet{
    id: number;
    text: string;
    image: string;
    profileImage: string;
    name: string;
    username: string;
    date: number;
    state: TweetState;
}
```

TweetState is an enum with 4 states, new, approved, favorite and denied.

I want to show them each one in a different tab, and when the user click on the corresponding button, change the state and therefor change the tab where it is.

This is my html:

```
<mat-tab-group mat-selected="selectedTab" mat-border-bottom mat-autoselect mat-swipe-content>
  <mat-tab label="NEW" class="tab" fxLayout="row">
      <app-tweet *ngFor="let tweet of campaign.tweets | new" [tweet]="tweet"></app-tweet>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="FAVORITE" class="tab">
    <app-tweet *ngFor="let tweet of campaign.tweets | favorite" [tweet]="tweet"></app-tweet>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="APPROVED" class="tab">    
    <app-tweet *ngFor="let tweet of campaign.tweets | approved" [tweet]="tweet"></app-tweet>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="DENIED" class="tab">
    <app-tweet *ngFor="let tweet of campaign.tweets | denied" [tweet]="tweet"></app-tweet>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

The pipes work fine, at least at the initial state. When I click the button to change the state, the state changes correctly but it doesn't switches tab.

I imagine that the *ngFor directive runs when the DOM is created and I should remove it from one place and add it on the other manually. What is the best approach? An Observable?

This is the Tweet template

```
<mat-card class="tweet">
  <mat-card-header>
    <img matCardAvatar src="{{tweet.profileImage}}" alt="{{tweet.username}}">
    <mat-card-title>{{tweet.name}}</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>{{tweet.username}}</mat-card-subtitle>
  </mat-card-header>
  <img mat-card-image src="{{tweet.image}}" alt="{{tweet.username}}">
  <mat-card-content>
      <p>
        {{tweet.text}}
      </p>
      <p>
        {{tweet.state}}
      </p>
    </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions>
    <div fxFlex="auto" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center">
      <span class="material-icons unselectable" (click)="setApproved()">thumb_up</span>
      <span class="material-icons unselectable" (click)="setDenied()">thumb_down</span>
      <span class="material-icons unselectable" (click)="setFavorite()">star</span>
    </div>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your issue is the data update, the reason why it isn't updating is because you didn't tell Angular that you have altered the state of `tweets`.

Where you have `*ngFor="tweet of campaign.tweets"`, you should change over to an observable. `*ngFor="tweet of (tweets$ | async)"` where in your component or the parent component generate the Observable on the fly.
For example in the same component for this template you could do.

```
//the component boiler plate stuff
export class MyTweetComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() tweets$: Observable<Tweet[]> //parse your campaign object up front.

  ngOnInit() {} // initialize tweets$ here if you got a service or something.
  ngOnChanges() {} //tell angular to detect changes (you may add additional logic here for handling tweets)

  constructor() { } //if you have a service to grab tweets you can inject it here

}
```

The `async` pipe will handle the subscription for you, all you have to do is in the component pass the observable of tweets down from parent or initialize it.